# Configuring dedicated directory for lock files and auto save files on MS-Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, auto-save, lock-files

How do I configure a dedicated location for lock files and auto-save files that works on MS-Windows, GNU/Linux, and macOS? I'm using GNU Emacs 28.2

The following works on GNU/Linux but not on MS-Windows for me:

```
(setq lock-file-name-transforms
      '(("\\`/.*/\\([^/]+\\)\\'" "~/.emacs.d/backup/\\1" t))
      auto-save-file-name-transforms
      '(("\\`/.*/\\([^/]+\\)\\'" "~/.emacs.d/backup/\\1" t)))
```

However, my backup directory setting does work for both GNU/Linux and MS-Windows:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist '((".*" . "~/.emacs.d/backup/")))
```

Answer (score 1):

> The following works on GNU/Linux but not on MS-Windows for me:
>
> ```lisp
> (setq lock-file-name-transforms
>       '(("\\`/.*/\\([^/]+\\)\\'" "~/.emacs.d/backup/\\1" t))
>       auto-save-file-name-transforms
>       '(("\\`/.*/\\([^/]+\\)\\'" "~/.emacs.d/backup/\\1" t)))
> ```

This is obviously because a pathname on MS-Windows doesn't begin with `/` -- but you wrote `` "\\`/..." ``.
You might want to correct it to `` "\\`[[:alpha:]]:/..." ``.

Comment: use `system-type` to determine whether Emacs is running on MS-Windows

Comment: Some MS-Windows pathnames do begin with `/`, like `//wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/...`

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky: I see no need to mention `//wsl` here *if you don't say you use WSL in your question* -- if you want to take WSL into consideration, what about FTP, SSH? ||| If you use WSL, say it in your question. If not, please let me know whether my answer solves your problem.